# Use map to show and hide components in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects in angular 2.  It's always going to be small, so I'm just rendering it with ngFor.  I want to show an edit icon next to each item and when you click it, replace the text with an edit box and save and cancel icons.  Here is the back end, this code is setting up the Map before showing the dialog.

```
  public open() {
    this.showEdit = new Map<number, boolean>();

    for(let n =0;n < this.authService.families.length;++n)
    {
      this.showEdit[n] = false;
    }

    this.opened = true;
  }
```

Then, here is my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let f of authService.families; let i = index">
  <span *ngIf="!showEdit[index]"> {{f.name}} </span>
  <span *ngIf="showEdit[index]">
    <input type="text" value="{{f.name}}"/>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" (click)="onSave(f.id, i)"></span>
  </span>
   <span *ngIf="!showEdit[index]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" (click)="onEdit(f.id, i)"></span>
</div>
```

So, we show the name, and the method should toggle the value in the Map (it does) and ngIf should then toggle and show the other control.  This does not work.  Clicking the toggle does nothing.

The issue appears to be with the map, because if I create a stand alone boolean and use that, it works fine....

Thanks

Comment: OK, I got this working by doing ngIf on a method that returns the value from the Map.  I'd still love to know why the original code did not work, but.

Comment: did you get any error ?

Comment: Nope - just didn't work.  All I changed was make the ngIf call a method, and the method returned the value from the map.